# Deploying bluechannel with fastcgi

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get a basic blue-channel website running through fcgi, I have a django.fcgi file. How do I do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read The Fabulous Manual](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#apache-setup)

Comment: Its shared hosting, I cant access apache settings. Thank you

Comment: Most shared hosts have FastCGI set up already and you can do the mod_rewrite rules through a .htaccess rule. For example, here's the Dreamhost Wiki post on setting django up: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Django